# Android GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener like functionality in iOS

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

In android I've used **[GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)** 
in a custom **View** to programmatically show scrolling (**Scroller**,**OverScroller**) by computing from **computeScroll** method of **View**

I am looking for same behavior in ***iOS*** , I tried to use **[Gesture Recognizers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html)** but couldn't find all the methods that were required.

Android Code :

```
    GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
      void onScroll(params){
        countXYDistanceAndOrientation(params)
      }
      void onFling(params)
        OverScroller.fling(params)
      }
    }
    View.computeScroll(){
      calcutesomething...
      Scroller.computeScrollOffset()
      OverScroller.computeScrollOffset()
    }
```

If there is any alternative implementation in **UIView** that can be used,that suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `UIScrollView` and `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

[Gesture Recognizers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html) should helps. You can add any gensture recognizers to your custom view.